# Listing defined functions in Bash

Tags: bash, introspection

I'm trying to write some code in bash which uses introspection to select the appropriate function to call.

Determining the candidates requires knowing which functions are defined. It's easy to list defined *variables* in bash using only parameter expansion:

```
$ prefix_foo="one"
$ prefix_bar="two"
$ echo "${!prefix_*}"
prefix_bar prefix_foo
```

However, doing this for *functions* appears to require filtering the output of set -- a much more haphazard approach.

Is there a Right Way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list the functions defined in my shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471364/how-do-i-list-the-functions-defined-in-my-shell)

Comment: @amphetamachine, hmm. Good question whether to close this as a duplicate of the other, or the inverse -- this one was first of the two to be asked, and has more answers (10 vs 8). Do you have a reason to prefer this direction, of the two possible approaches?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about [compgen](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html):

```
compgen -A function   # compgen is a shell builtin
```

Comment: Perfect! Simple, clean, and even allows prefix matching (as in: `compgen -A function prefix_`)

Comment: ...except, an important caveat: this only works with copies of bash having interactive extensions enabled. That excludes the default copy of bash on NixOS, f/e.

Comment: Related: [Can bash show a function's definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916856)

Answer (score 13):

```
$ declare -F
declare -f ::
declare -f _get_longopts
declare -f _longopts_func
declare -f _onexit
...
```

So, Jed Daniel's alias,

```
declare -F | cut -d" " -f3
```

cuts on a space and echos the 3rd field:

```
$ declare -F | cut -d" " -f3
::
_get_longopts
_longopts_func
_onexit
```

Answer (score 6):

I have an entry in my `.bashrc` that says:

```
alias list='declare -F |cut -d" " -f3'
```

Which allows me to type `list` and get a list of functions. When I added it, I probably understood what was happening, but I can't remember to save my life at the moment.

Good luck,

--jed

Comment: declare -F |cut -d" " -f3 |egrep -v "^_"

Answer (score 3):

Use the declare builtin to list currently defined functions:

```
declare -F
```

Comment: Helpful (though several other folks already suggested it), but not sufficient in and of itself; the output still needs to be processed into an array to be similar to `${!prefix_*}`, and adding `cut` to the command line isn't as clean as sticking to builtins.

Answer (score 3):

`zsh` only (not what was asked for, but all the more generic questions have been closed as a duplicate of this):

```
typeset -f +
```

From `man zshbuiltins`:

```
-f     The  names  refer  to functions rather than parameters.
 +     If `+' appears by itself in a separate word as the last
       option, then the names of all parameters (functions with -f)
       are printed, but  the values  (function  bodies)  are not.
```

Example:

```
martin@martin ~ % cat test.zsh 
#!/bin/zsh

foobar()
{
  echo foobar
}

barfoo()
{
  echo barfoo
}

typeset -f +
```

Output:

```
martin@martin ~ % ./test.zsh
barfoo
foobar
```

Answer (score 2):

This has no issues with IFS nor globbing:

```
readarray -t funcs < <(declare -F)

printf '%s\n' "${funcs[@]##* }"
```

Of course, that needs bash 4.0.

For bash since 2.04 use (a little trickier but equivalent):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a funcs < <(declare -F)
```

If you need that the exit code of this option is zero, use this:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a funcs < <( declare -F && printf '\0' )
```

It will exit unsuccesful (not 0) if either `declare` or `read` fail. (Thanks to **@CharlesDuffy**)

Comment: Good call -- I didn't think about reading the `declare -f`s into the array and stripping them back out at expansion time. Might make it `declare -F && printf '\0'` inside the process substitution in the 2.0.4 case -- that way the `read` will have an exit status of zero (and, as a bonus, any error that somehow stopped `declare -F` from working would be effectively passed through).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, added.

Answer (score 1):

One (ugly) approach is to grep through the output of set:

```
set \
  | egrep '^[^[:space:]]+ [(][)][[:space:]]*$' \
  | sed -r -e 's/ [(][)][[:space:]]*$//'
```

Better approaches would be welcome.

Comment: In bash, "ugly" is on the left-hand of the sliding scale.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
funcs=($(declare -F))      # create an array
IFS="$saveIFS"
funcs=(${funcs[@]##* })    # keep only what's after the last space
```

Then, run at the Bash prompt as an example displaying bash-completion functions:

```
$ for i in ${funcs[@]}; do echo "$i"; done
__ack_filedir
__gvfs_multiple_uris
_a2dismod
. . .
$ echo ${funcs[42]}
_command
```

Comment: Very nice, though the IFS twiddling on both ends makes things a little ugly. OTOH, the variant that comes off the top of my head to avoid it involve a subshell and string splitting (ie. `funcs=( $(IFS=$'\n'; funcs=($(declare -F)); echo "${funcs[@]##* }") )`), and which is certainly much more functional (as opposed to aesthetic) ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

This collects a list of function names matching any of a list of patterns:

```
functions=$(for c in $patterns; do compgen -A function | grep "^$c\$")
```

The grep limits the output to only exact matches for the patterns.

Check out the bash command [type](http://ss64.com/bash/type.html) as a better alternative to the following.  Thanks to Charles Duffy for the clue.

The following uses that to answer the title question for humans rather than shell scripts:  it adds a list of function names matching the given patterns, to the regular `which` list of shell scripts, to answer, "What code runs when I type a command?"

```
which() {
  for c in "$@"; do
    compgen -A function |grep "^$c\$" | while read line; do
      echo "shell function $line" 1>&2
     done
    /usr/bin/which "$c"
   done
 }
```

So,

```
(xkcd)Sandy$ which deactivate
shell function deactivate
(xkcd)Sandy$ which ls
/bin/ls
(xkcd)Sandy$ which .\*run_hook
shell function virtualenvwrapper_run_hook
```

This is arguably a violation of the Unix "do one thing" philosophy, but I've more than once been desperate because `which` wasn't finding a command that some package was supposed to contain, me forgetting about shell functions, so I've put this in my .profile.

Comment: Can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: That looks rather like it's built to answer a different question -- using `which` plays no role in listing defined functions at all.

Comment: @Bernhard, hopefully it's a little clearer now.
@CharlesDuffy, Yes.  I am not using the existing `which` to list defined functions, I'm adding a defined function list _to_ `which`.  I've edited the post to say why.

Comment: @FutureNerd, if the goal is to answer "what happens when I run this command?", then how does this differ from what `type` does out-of-the-box? (Also, `type` handles things such as builtins, shell syntax, and the like that this does not).

Comment: @Charles, thanks for the clue!  How this differs is that this works if I forget "type" and type "which".  Maybe I'll define "which" as an alias for "type", heh.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# list-defined-functions.sh
# Lists functions defined in this script.
# 
# Using `compgen -A function`,
# We can save the list of functions defined before running out script,
# the compare that to a new list at the end,
# resulting in the list of newly added functions.
# 
# Usage:
#   bash list-defined-functions.sh      # Run in new shell with no predefined functions
#   list-defined-functions.sh           # Run in current shell with plenty of predefined functions
#

# Example predefined function
foo() { echo 'y'; }

# Retain original function list
# If this script is run a second time, keep the list from last time
[[ $original_function_list ]] || original_function_list=$(compgen -A function)

# Create some new functions...
myfunc() { echo "myfunc is the best func"; }
function another_func() { echo "another_func is better"; }
function superfunction { echo "hey another way to define functions"; }
# ...

# function goo() { echo ok; }

[[ $new_function_list ]] || new_function_list=$(comm -13 \
    <(echo $original_function_list) \
    <(compgen -A function))

echo "Original functions were:"
echo "$original_function_list"
echo 
echo "New Functions defined in this script:"
echo "$new_function_list"
```

Comment: Why the echo? `<(compgen -A function)` would be more efficient. Might also put the work of the grep into the awk line: `awk '/>/ {print $2}'`, removing the redundency there. Actually -- better to ditch `diff` altogether; it's **vastly** less efficient than `comm` when all you want to do is set comparisons.

Comment: (Beyond that -- nifty! The question this answers isn't the one that I asked, but it's still moderately useful to have around in case someone else stumbles upon this question looking for something different).

Comment: Thanks Charles! I've learned so much about Bash over the last week. Workin' on a boilerplate type thing at the moment to try and learn cool stuff. https://gist.github.com/deanrather/5719199

Comment: One more quibble: Expansions should be inside quotes. `echo "$foo"` is better than `echo $foo`, inasmuch as the latter expands globs, string-splits on runs of whitespace (and lets the `echo` command reassemble them -- thereby changing newlines and tabs to spaces), and otherwise does undesirable things.

Comment: ...compare `foo='*'; echo $foo` to `foo='*'; echo "$foo"`.

Comment: Actually, this only works the first time you source a file. If you were to source it again, the `original_function_list` would contain all the functions from the previous time. What is I need is some way to finalise that list, make it read-only..

Comment: You don't need to make it read-only, you only need to check whether it's set. `[[ $original_function_list ]] || original_function_list=$(...)`