# Can bash show a function's definition?

Tags: bash, function

Is there a way to view a bash function's definition in bash?

For example, say I defined the function `foobar`

```
function foobar {
    echo "I'm foobar"
}
```

Is there any way to later get the code that `foobar` runs?

```
$ # non-working pseudocode
$ echo $foobar
echo "I'm foobar"
```

Answer (score 478, accepted):

Use `type`. If `foobar` is e.g. defined in your `~/.profile`:

```
$ type foobar
foobar is a function
foobar {
    echo "I'm foobar"
}
```

This does find out what `foobar` was, and if it was defined as a function it calls `declare -f` as explained by pmohandras.

To print out just the body of the function (i.e. the code) use `sed`:

```
type foobar | sed '1,3d;$d'
```

Comment: @sjsupersumit The question explicitly asks for a Bash solution.

Comment: `type` will also expand aliases, which is a nice bonus :)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It doesn't show the definition of the function, it only shows which file it came from.

Comment: @gman I had the same issue. You are probably using zsh. In that case, `declare -f function_name` will work on both bash and zsh

Answer (score 323):

You can display the definition of a function in bash using declare. For example:

```
declare -f foobar
```

Comment: Great, to the point, works even when functions defined in other loaded script files. Works also in zsh.

Comment: Works with old shells on non-linux systems if you use `typeset -f`

Comment: good also that it just shows the `function` definition, so you don't have to parse if that's what you want.

Comment: The best answer is on the bottom. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Works also in `zsh`.

Comment: This should be the main answer, none of the other worked for me (with .zsh).

Answer (score 8):

```
set | sed -n '/^foobar ()/,/^}/p'
```

This basically prints the lines from your set command starting with the function name foobar () and ending with }

Comment: I'm positively surprised that the `set` output has a) comments stripped out, and b) normalized the white space between function name and parens. I'm still reluctant to use this as there may be variables that contain `}` that may trip the simple parsing.

Answer (score 4):

```
set | grep -A999 '^foobar ()' | grep -m1 -B999 '^}'
```

with foobar being the function name.

Comment: problem: will only display up to the first "}", which is not everything whenever the defintion contains nestings of "{...}" which indeed Bash does allow.

Comment: Can also fail if the function contains a here-doc/here-string containing the curly-brace pattern