# Save the old value of a function bash, so that it can be called later

Tags: bash

Is it possible to save the old function (named `foo`) in such a way that you can call it within a new function (also named `foo`), perhaps from a different name, or such?

To make this concrete, here's specifically what I'm trying to do:

In bash, the `command_not_found_handle` is a function which, if defined, is called whenever bash cannot find the command which the user is trying to run. For example, Ubuntu uses this to suggest packages which can be installed:

```
$ pv
The program 'pv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install pv
```

This is really *nice*, and I'd like to keep this behavior. However, I'd *also* like to add another `command_not_found` handle, which simply runs a given `DEFAULT_COMMAND` with whatever command line the user typed, like so:

```
$ DEFAULT_COMMAND=git
$ status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working
directory)

        modified:   .bashrc
        modified:   .gitconfig
        modified:   .vimrc

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .bash_profile
        .gitglobalignore
        .gvimrc
        node_modules/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

---

I already have a function which does the above, and it works like a dream; however, using it **overrides** the default Ubuntu `command_not_found` handle, which can be handy to have when I can't remember a package name for a given executable.

How do I get both? Thanks!

NB: The obvious solution is to find and copy the Ubuntu built-in `command_not_found` logic into my script; but that is not ideal, because it means I have to manually update it later, when Ubuntu changes the way they do things. I'm hoping for something more generic, if possible.

Edit: It would be best not to have to resort to string manipulation, as can be done by saving the *text* of the function to a variable, mangling it, then `eval`ing it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916856/can-bash-show-a-functions-definition for how to get the function definition. You can replace the function name and call `eval` to execute it.

Comment: Thanks! `declare -f` gets me most of the way there! If you feel like writing it out, I'll give you "Accepted answer" for this; elsewise, I can.

Comment: This isn't really quite a duplicate. I'm trying to accomplish a different thing, and it's useful to know whether http://stackoverflow.com/q/6916856/712526 is the best way. (I was really hoping it could be done without string manipulation)

Comment: If I just post an answer saying to use `declare -f command_not_found`, that's essentially a duplicate. So unless I go the extra step and write the code that parses it, so it can save it with a new name, it's not really an answer. You can answer your own question, so I suggest you do so.

Comment: I can see you don't need (or mind) the rep. I was just being overly cordial. I'll have a solution together in the next hour.

Comment: Yeah, I lose this much rep in my seat cushions. :)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for all your help. Be sure to put plastic under your couch, to catch all the loose rep!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Barmar's suggestion, I was able to implement a workable
solution. The following function can be used to rename an arbitrary
bash function to another name.

```
renameFunction () {
    local oldName="$1"; shift
    local newName="$1"

    local definition="$(declare -f "$oldName")"
    if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo >&2 "renameFunction: $oldName is not a function"
        return
    fi

    if declare -f  "$newName" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
        echo >&2 "renameFunction: $newName is already defined"
        return
    fi

    eval "$(echo "${definition/"$oldName"/"$newName"}")"
    # Does not work for recursive functions (like "//" would), but also
    # doesn't break if $oldName is a substring of something else

    unset "$oldName"
}
```

#### Notes

- The last line

  ```
  unset "$oldName"
  ```

  is optional — and without it, this becomes a "copy function" utility.
- The pattern substitution would work for a recursive function if it were
  changed to the following (note the `//`):

  ```
  eval "$(echo "${definition//"$oldName"/"$newName"}")"
  ```

  However, this fails if the function name is a substring of something
  else within the definition. Since recursion is relatively rare in shell
  scripts, I took the less brittle approach.
- The quoting is *correct*, despite being too complex for the SO syntax
  highlighter. (The quoting is also unnecessary, unless you like
  to play with `$IFS`.)

---

For completeness' sake, here's how I'm using this function:

```
# The DEFAULT_CMD is the command to run if the command line could
# not be understood.  Set the DEFAULT_CMD to git, once; the user can
# change it at any time
DEFAULT_CMD=git

# Save the old command_not_found_handle for reuse
renameFunction command_not_found_handle __PREVIOUS_COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_HANDLE

command_not_found_handle () {
    eval '"$DEFAULT_CMD" $DEFAULT_CMD_PREFIX_ARGS "$@" $DEFAULT_CMD_POSTFIX_ARGS'
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
        __PREVIOUS_COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_HANDLE "$@"
    fi
}
export DEFAULT_CMD
```

`command_not_found_handle` is called by `bash` whenever it cannot find
program or command that the user specified. It receives as its arguments
the entire command-line.

This function tries to execute the command-line as a "sub command" of
the given `DEFAULT_CMD`. If it does not succeed, it tries the old
`command_not_found_handle`

Comment: I don't like this solution because of the string mangling and `eval`ing. Can you, gentle reader, do better? :-)